# Queue processing solution to replace scheduled task

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, message-queue, background-process, servicebus, service-broker

Before posting in SO, I posted in forums.asp.net but got no useful response.

I have MVC web app & a C# console app.

My users upload photos to our web server & uploads queued in DB with detail info. The console reads from the DB Queue and go through process pipeline such as:

Reformat the file (run a bat command), create entry in database (MongoDB), publish the file and send user email notification (plus others)

Currently we have a C# console app that is scheduled to run every 5 mins.

Problems with scheduled task:
1) User file doesn't get processed immediately as it has to wait for next run

2) Large file may take longer than 5 mins to process

3) I want multiple threads access and processing the queue in parallel

4) Better error handling

Something like this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/hh367520.aspx

But my app will not run in the Azure cloud.

Are there any library (open source) that I can use to do this in .NET MVC app?

Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Service bus for windows server (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn282144.aspx) is effectively the azure bus for local servers and would be what you're looking for based on your question.

There are other messaging technologies that could be used MSMQ, ZeroMQ, RabbitMQ, RhinoBus and each have their strengths and weaknesses. Personally I find the service bus to be a robust, configurable queuing system but can be a bit over the top depending on what you need. Check out http://queues.io/ for a fairly lengthy list of options.

Comment: I will prefer some solution library that is open source and work in Windows and Linux box. I am still looking...

Comment: Looking at the docs, it seems it is mainly for Azure and needs quite a bit of  ramp up

Comment: It's actually the exact same bus that azure uses they are equivalent in terms of power and usage. If you look at implentation of using one it's pretty much the same on the other. There are set up differences and that's about it. As far as open source out of the box look at ZeroMQ and RabbitMQ. ZeroMQ is more if a sockets on crack type of implementation that requires some effort to build the sender and receiver but it'll get the job done.